# How to validate if the input time is within the given time range in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My time range is 08:00 AM to 03:00 PM.

If the selected input time does not exist within this range it should throw an error message.

How to do this?
Can anybody help me out?

```
   protected void txtTimeIn_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimeIn.Text);

        TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);

        TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);

        TimeSpan now = new TimeSpan(time.Ticks);

        if ((now > start) && (now < end))

        {


            lblIN.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lblIN.Visible = true;

        }
    }
```

When i select the wrong time the label is displayed, but once i change and select the correct time the label is not disappearing.

Comment: You answered your own question. The time must be `greater` than 8AM and `less` then 3PM. Use the greater-than/less-than sign. There you go.

Comment: Use ````TimeSpans````.  You can create two new ones for 8 AM and 3 PM, and see if the DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay is within those TimeSpans.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimeIn.Text);
            TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan now = new TimeSpan(time.Ticks);
            if ((now > start) && (now < end))
            {
                
                lblIn.Visible=false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblIN.Visible = true;

            }     I used time span but once i change the correct time the error message is not disappearing

Comment: Your logic seems off.  ````if (now > start && now < end)````  then you know you're in that time frame...throw the error.

Comment: And you don't need to add a new ````now```` TimeSpan.  Just use the ````time.TimeOfDay```` from the initial variable you declared with the input.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);  // 8 AM
        TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);  // 3 PM

        if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > startTime && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < endTime)
        {
            // Execute logic
        }

    }
```

Here is a quick and easy solution to check against the current DateTime.  Obviously you said you have a "selected date" but I don't see that anywher, so just convert that to a DateTime if needed.

Comment: I don't think startTime and endTime should be TimeSpans. TimeSpan represents the time between those points.

Comment: Is there any regular expression to validate the time range?

Comment: If you're trying to find out if a time is within a selected time frame, then that is the whole point of ````TimeSpans```` not regular expressions